# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to run the sql script in my project. I have a sql script, its contents on the first picture[image] 
I also had to create a data source, this is shown in the picture 2.[image] And I have a code in which I try to establish a connection and run my sql script.

```
public class DBManager {
    private static DBManager instance;
    private static Connection connection;
    private static final Lock CONNECTION_LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=false";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String pass = "root";


    private static final String SQL_INSERT_USER = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (DEFAULT ,?)";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT_GROUP = "INSERT INTO groups VALUES (DEFAULT ,?)";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL_USERS = "SELECT * FROM users";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL_GROUPS = "SELECT * FROM groups";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_USER_BY_LOGIN = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_GROUP_BY_NAME = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name=?";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT_USER_TO_GROUP = "INSERT INTO users_groups VALUES (?, ?)";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_GROUPS_BY_USER_ID = "SELECT g.id, g.name FROM users_groups ug\n" +
            "JOIN users u ON ug.user_id = u.id\n" +
            "JOIN groups g ON ug.group_id = g.id\n" +
            "WHERE u.id = ?";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE_GROUP = "DELETE FROM groups WHERE name=?";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE_GROUP = "UPDATE groups SET name=? WHERE id=?";


    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    private DBManager(String url, String user, String pass) throws Exception {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        executeScript(connection, new FileInputStream("sql/db-create.sql"));
    }

    public static synchronized DBManager getInstance()throws Exception {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBManager(url, user, pass);
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

And the class that runs the project.

```
public class Demo {
    //todo close all connections and scanners

    private static <T> void printList(List<T> list) {
        for (T element : list) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // users  ==> [ivanov]; groups ==> [teamA]

        DBManager dbManager = DBManager.getInstance();
     }
}
```

And i get an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2440)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at database.DBManager.executeScript(DBManager.java:350)
    at database.DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:48)
    at database.DBManager.getInstance(DBManager.java:53)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:20)
```

Do I do everything right? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

The message error is clear, to solve your problem you have to specify the name of database in the url :

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false";
                                                               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I already tried to do it. I get the following exception. Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'people'

Comment: this is another problem @VIRICH in this case it seems that you don't have a people database, you have to create it manually or you can follow this tutorial to create via java http://www.kode-blog.com/jdbc-create-database-dynamically-create-databases